# Vue 2 Using external variables inside Instance

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a **Laravel 5.5** & **Vue 2.x** project which requires to define some data in the "front-end" and use them in the Vue Instance:

First, I have my view or HTML file:

```
<fieldset class="form-group col-md">
    <label for="country" class="control-label">Country</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" v-model="selectedCountry" @change="selectCountry()">
        <option :value="null" :selected="selectedCountry">Select one</option>
        <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.id">@{{ country.name }}</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>

<script>
    var formSelectedCountry = {{ isset($property) ? $property->country_id : "null" }};
    var formSelectedDepartment = {{ isset($property) ? $property->department_id : "null" }};
    var formSelectedLocation = {{ isset($property) ? $property->location_id : "null" }};
    var formSelectedZone = {{ isset($property) ? $property->zone_id : "null" }};
</script>
```

This works fine. But in other pages where `formSelectedCountry` (for instance) is not defined Vue seems not to work.

I have this in my **app.js**:

```
data: {
    ...
    selectedCountry: formSelectedCountry,
    selectedDepartment: formSelectedDepartment,
    selectedLocation: formSelectedLocation,
    selectedZone:  formSelectedZone,
    ...
}
```

I have also tried to prepend these lines in order to "pre-define" them:

```
formSelectedCountry: '',
formSelectedDepartment: '',
formSelectedLocation: '',
formSelectedZone: '',
```

Or maybe there is a way to set the data with `selectedCountry: (formSelectedCountry ? formSelectedCountry : null`.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) lifecycle hook, for example

```
var formSelectedCountry = {{ isset($property) ? $property->country_id : "null" }};
var formSelectedDepartment = {{ isset($property) ? $property->department_id : "null" }};
var formSelectedLocation = {{ isset($property) ? $property->location_id : "null" }};
var formSelectedZone = {{ isset($property) ? $property->zone_id : "null" }};
new Vue({
 data: {
 ...
 selectedCountry: '',
 selectedDepartment: '',
 selectedLocation: '',
 selectedZone:  '',
 ...
 },
 created:function(){
   this.selectedCountry = formSelectedCountry;
   this.selectedDepartment= formSelectedDepartment;
   this.selectedLocation= formSelectedLocation;
   this.selectedZone= formSelectedZone;
 }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4yjg2LLz/